# Did i simpifly this correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify $$\frac{\frac{1}{x+h-1} - \frac{1}{x-1}}{h} \ \ ? $$

I can't figure out how to do it correctly on the website.

I got $\frac{1}{(h+x-1)(x-1)}$

Comment: This is impossible to read.  [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting.  Or you could try just adding parentheses.  My guess would be that you meant $\frac 1h \times \left(\frac 1{x+h}-\frac 1{x-1}\right)$ but it is just a guess.

Comment: How did you get there ? Show your intermediate steps. At a first glance it doesn´t look right.

Comment: I added a photo, thanks for the the guide.

Comment: I'd say this doesn't really need any simplification to be honest

Comment: @MathProb one should not change the meaning of question of the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost right. You have forgotten the negative sign.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}-\frac{1}{(h+x-1)(x-1)}=\lim_{h\to 0}-\frac{1}{h(x-1)+x(x-1)-(x-1)}=-\frac{1}{x(x-1)-(x-1)}$$

$$=-\frac1{x^2-x-x+1}=-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$

This is the derivative of $\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Comment: @Pete523 You´re welcome.